# Android ImageView set selector programatically dosen't work

Tags: android, imageview

temp_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/color1" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/color2" />
    <item android:color="@color/color3" />
</selector>
```

And I applied it through the code below

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.temp_selector))
```

I don't know why it doesn't work... What should I do?
(**It has to be applied programatically. not xml**.)

Comment: What API version of android is your device running?

Answer (score 0):

**Use** below to change color

```
imageView.isSelected = true 
imageView.isSelected = false
```

**Use below selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/color3" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/color2" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/color1" android:state_pressed="true" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: yes, this working for me, i am just using drawable instead of colors , updated the code

Comment: It doesn't work.. I don't know why..
I change the isSelected value of ImageView. But ImageView'scolor is color3..